# How to show record number in Crystal report by using C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a page with two column in Crystal Report, but I want to show Record number at column 1 from number 1 to 5 and column 2 from 6 to 12 record. How can I do it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Insert the **Special Field** called ***Record Number***:
[image]